# Как выполнить запрос хранимых процедур в java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Моя проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно из хранимых процедур получить информации через классы java. Вызываю как обычно процедуру через callablestatement, дальше не понял как оно работает мне нужно взять из него данные и поставить на форму. Больше всего показывают пример из mysql, но я использую microsoft sql server. Можете написать код для его реализацию и через какой класс использовать для вывода результата. 
Я использую его так:

```
            String sql = "{call stored_procedure_name}";
            String URL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost;DatabaseName=raspisanie";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, login, pwd);
            CallableStatement proc = conn.prepareCall(sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так:

```
String sql = "{? = call stored_procedure_name(?)}";
//...
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.CURSOR);
callableStatement.executeQuery();

ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);
while (resultSet.next()) {
//... resultSet.getString("NAME")
}
```

Comment: вместо вопросительного не нужно ничего писать или параметры